# Where do i put the ADO script in Excel?

Tags: excel, ado

For something i was trying to do in Excel i was suggested to use a ado script. i was given the ADO script as well. But I have no idea where do i put this script in excel. Can anyone please help? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In excel you can access the Visual Basic editor and enter your script there. In 2007 there is a developer tab with a button that says "Visual basic". <strike>I cannot remember what it looked like in previous versions.</strike> In 2003 : **Tools>Macros>VisualBasic Editor**.

Comment: Alt+F11 is a quick way to the code windows for all of MS Office.